# How to make paragraph move with the size of the image on the website? (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, position

I'm trying to put the paragraph exactly below the left edge of an image. The problem is that I cannot make the paragraph stay on the left edge of an image whenever the user resizes the website. Whenever the image moves, the paragraph stays on the left side of the web browser.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class = "main_car">
        <img src="main_car.jpg" alt="car">
        <p>June, 2020. Sunshine Coast, BC, Canada </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 90%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main_car img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: auto;
}

.main_car p {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.425);
    font-size: 10px;
}

.main_car {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case you should flexbox.

```
.main_car { 
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
flex-direction: column;
```

This page gives great instructions how to use flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the CSS property position:fixed on the div in which you have placed your paragraph